# Executing code when server response has ended - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to figure out how to output the elements of an array to the console when a server response has come to an end.

This is the code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
    response = response.setEncoding('utf8');
    var data = [];

    response.on('data', function (collect) {
        data.push(collect);
    });

    response.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

});
```

Where and how do I use response.end event to print out all of the elements of the `data` array using `console.log()` method?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You'd just add it anywhere inside the callback, did you try something ?

Comment: I tried `response.end(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    });`

but it does not work as response.end is not a function.

Comment: Use `response.on('end',`, also since the chunks (yours collect) is string it would make sence to do `data += collect` instead of `push` this assumes you define data as string `var data = '';`

Comment: @Molda Thank you for pointing that out! Makes it much more efficient and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was staring me right in the face! I didn't need to call the `response.end` method, instead i needed to call the `response.on` method and pass it the `end` event.

Here is what worked for me:

```
response.on('end',function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    });
```

Full code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
    response = response.setEncoding('utf8');
    var data = [];

    response.on('data', function (collect) {
        data.push(collect);
    });

    response.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    response.on('end',function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    });

});
```